# Should trading result be the same for data in reverse order in simple NN?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a simple neural net that takes an input (20 day price change) and tries to predict the future price change of a stock (A). On top of this is a simple rule to go either long or short.

Just to see what might happen, I created an artificial price (AR) which is stock A's prices in reverse order. Stock A has had strong growth, so stock AR appears to have had a strong decline.

When I run (repeatedly) my NN system on both stocks - I would expect the result to be similar. However, 1 does consistently, considerably better than the other.

Does anyone think this is odd?

Comment: Hi, if there is something wrong with my question - or perhaps this is the wrong forum, I would be grateful if somebody could let me know.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE? There is no perfect optimization method to estimate the weights of the neural network. Very likely, the hyperparameters you are using are making them stuck to some local minima. Also, make sure your results are not a fluke. As said, nnet estimation is incredibly stochastic.

Comment: What does "better" mean when you say that one is better than the other?